# TreeMap isn't sorted properly

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary, properties, treemap

I am trying to extract data from a properties-file and put it in a map. More precisely: I have a `Properties` object, wherein the file has the following content:

```
something = Blah
somethingElse = BlahBlah
andAgain = BlahBlahBlah
# Parameters
param1 = One
param2 = Two
param3 = Three
# and so on...
param9 = Nine
```

I am now trying to extract the key and value only of the properties with the key `param...` and put them in a `TreeMap`. The sorting should stay the same as in the properties-file (`param1`, ... `param9`). This is my code so far:

```
/*
 * First extract the properties which are stored in external file
 */
Properties props = extractProperties();
Map<String, String> sortedMap = new TreeMap<String, String>();
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
if (checkPropertiesAvailable()) {
    Enumeration e = props.propertyNames();
    // iterate over properties
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
        String key = (String) e.nextElement();
        // put key/value in HashMap
        map.put(key, props.getProperty(key));
        if (key.contains("param")) {
            // 
            sortedMap.put(key, props.getProperty(key));
        }
    }
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : sortedMap.entrySet()) {
        system.out.println("Value: " + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the parameters (`param1`, ... `param9`) are not sorted properly and I can't figure out how they are sorted at the moment. What is going wrong and how can I sort the map?

I am grateful for any help!

Comment: Can you show the output that you got?

Comment: `TreeMap` is using the default `String` comparator, if you  want to change the sort order provide your own implementation of `comparator`

Comment: [Your code](https://gist.github.com/assylias/b837a37a05936239627c) works as expected... The problem may be in the original file (non-ascii characters?) or in `extractProperties` (encoding issue?)...

Comment: *"not sorted properly"* Then how *are* they sorted? Show us.

Answer (score 0):

Your code prints properties in a sorted way. Please check this code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class TreeMapExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        try (FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/example.properties")) {
            props = new Properties();
            props.load(input);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to load properties from file.");
        }

        Map<String, String> sortedMap = new TreeMap<>();

        Enumeration e = props.propertyNames();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            String key = (String) e.nextElement();
            if (key.contains("param")) {
                sortedMap.put(key, props.getProperty(key));
            }
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : sortedMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.printf("[Key, Value]: %s, %s \n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

        System.out.println();

        for (String s : sortedMap.keySet()) {
            System.out.printf("[Key, Value]: %s, %s \n", s, sortedMap.get(s));
        }

        System.out.println();

        for (String s : sortedMap.values()) {
            System.out.printf("Value: %s \n", s);
        }
    }
}
```

And output is:
 {code}

```
[Key, Value]: param1, One 
[Key, Value]: param2, Two 
[Key, Value]: param3, Three 
[Key, Value]: param9, Nine 

[Key, Value]: param1, One 
[Key, Value]: param2, Two 
[Key, Value]: param3, Three 
[Key, Value]: param9, Nine 

Value: One 
Value: Two 
Value: Three 
Value: Nine
```